# I wish to make short clips for my website from existing Final Cut shows

Tags: final-cut-pro

I have made a number of videos in Final Cut Pro and would like to make some short clips of these as demos in my website. What is the best way to do this? What is the best export format? I have a Weebly template website/

Comment: Are you asking about how to export from FCP, how to compress for the web or how to upload videos to weebly?